# Sign In with Google on Website with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, google-oauth

So, I'm a bit new with Python and I'm trying to achieve that my Script logins into a website automatically with my google credentials.

In resume, I need to follow a url to download some data from a website but it always requests me to sign in with google First. As I'm trying to do these downloads periodically in an automatic way, I first need to pass this "Sign In" page, so I can forward move to follow the URL to do this download.

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you download cookies to use again after logging in to the site you want to log in to with selenium, you can only log in by restoring the cookies.

You have to use [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) for it.

What you need to do is to log in within the specified time after opening the browser with Selenium and wait for the cookies to be saved.

**For downloading cookies:**

```
import time
import pickle

from selenium import webdriver as wb

driver = wb.Chrome()
driver.get("")#URL

time.sleep(200) #wait until you log in
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies, open('cookies.pkl', 'wb')) #for downloading cookies
```

**And using cookies after open browser to log in:**

```
file = open('cookies.pkl', 'rb')
cookies = pickle.load(file)
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

file.close()
```

I'd like point out of that these codes are for example purposes only, they may not solve your problem exactly, so you may need to change the codes, but the main purpose is to show you the logic of it.